# RabbitMQ connection issue

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am totally new to rabbitmq and I am stuck while consuming the events from rabbitmq. I am trying to read from rabbitmq and create a data frame. after receiving every 1000 events I am writing my data frame to redshift which took around 2 min to complete.

Now my problem is I am getting a channel closed error from pika after writing to redshift.

The error I am getting is,

> 2022-06-08 18:36:26:
> b'{"message":{"sku":"JOY010","totalStock":17,"distStock":{"WH-CGK45":{"qty":17},"WH-SRG18":{"qty":0},"WH-SUB51":{"qty":0},"WH-MES07":{"qty":0},"WH-UPG04":{"qty":0},"WH-AAP02":{"qty":0}}},"timestamp":1654691691086}'
> 2022-06-08 18:36:26: 1493 2022-06-08 18:36:26:
> b'{"message":{"sku":"JOY012","totalStock":50,"distStock":{"WH-CGK45":{"qty":50},"WH-SRG18":{"qty":0},"WH-SUB51":{"qty":0},"WH-MES07":{"qty":0},"WH-UPG04":{"qty":0},"WH-AAP02":{"qty":0}}},"timestamp":1654691691174}'
> 2022-06-08 18:36:26: connection_lost: StreamLostError: ("Stream
> connection lost: SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol
> (_ssl.c:2548)')",) 2022-06-08 18:36:26: AMQP stack terminated, failed
> to connect, or aborted: opened=True, error-arg=StreamLostError:
> ("Stream connection lost: SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of
> protocol (_ssl.c:2548)')",); pending-error=None 2022-06-08 18:36:26:
> Stack terminated due to StreamLostError: ("Stream connection lost:
> SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol
> (_ssl.c:2548)')",) 2022-06-08 18:36:26: Closing transport socket and
> unlinking: state=2; <ssl.SSLSocket fd=10,
> family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0,
> laddr=('192.168.224.32', 55119)> 2022-06-08 18:36:26: Unexpected
> connection close detected: StreamLostError: ("Stream connection lost:
> SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol
> (_ssl.c:2548)')",) Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/simtiaz/Documents/Development/Development/inventory_snapshot.py",
> line 46, in consume_message
> for method_frame, properties, body in channel.consume(rabbitmq_queue, False, False, None, 1800):   File
> "/Users/simtiaz/.conda/envs/Development/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py",
> line 1991, in consume
> self._process_data_events(time_limit=delta)   File "/Users/simtiaz/.conda/envs/Development/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py",
> line 2026, in _process_data_events
> self.connection.process_data_events(time_limit=time_limit)   File "/Users/simtiaz/.conda/envs/Development/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py",
> line 827, in process_data_events
> self._flush_output(timer.is_ready, common_terminator)   File "/Users/simtiaz/.conda/envs/Development/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py",
> line 523, in _flush_output
> raise self._closed_result.value.error pika.exceptions.StreamLostError: Stream connection lost:
> SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2548)')
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/simtiaz/Documents/Development/Development/inventory_snapshot.py",
> line 95, in consume_message
> requeued_messages = channel.cancel()   File "/Users/simtiaz/.conda/envs/Development/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py",
> line 2083, in cancel
> self.basic_cancel(self._queue_consumer_generator.consumer_tag)   File
> "/Users/simtiaz/.conda/envs/Development/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py",
> line 1756, in basic_cancel
> assert (consumer_info.cancelled_by_broker or AssertionError: ctag1.93ba887914d24c9c9782628d315a4bec
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/simtiaz/Documents/Development/Development/inventory_snapshot.py",
> line 104, in 
> consume_message()   File "/Users/simtiaz/Documents/Development/Development/inventory_snapshot.py",
> line 98, in consume_message
> channel.close()   File "/Users/simtiaz/.conda/envs/Development/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py",
> line 1513, in close
> self._impl._raise_if_not_open()   File "/Users/simtiaz/.conda/envs/Development/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pika/channel.py",
> line 1393, in _raise_if_not_open
> raise exceptions.ChannelWrongStateError('Channel is closed.') pika.exceptions.ChannelWrongStateError: Channel is closed.

My code is

````
    data = {}
    df_rabbit = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["SNP_DATE", "SNP_TIME", "SKU_CODE", "WAREHOUSE_CODE", "INVENTORY"])

    param = pika.URLParameters(rabbitmq_url)
    param._heartbeat = 1800
    param._blocked_connection_timeout = 1800

    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(param)
    channel = connection.channel()

    try:

        for method_frame, properties, body in channel.consume(rabbitmq_queue, False, False, None, 1800):
            logging.info(method_frame.delivery_tag)
            logging.info(body)

            json_msg = json.loads(body)

            SKU = json_msg["message"]["sku"]

            epoch = datetime.fromtimestamp(json_msg["timestamp"] / 1000)
            dt = epoch.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            tm = epoch.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

            warehouse = json_msg["message"]["distStock"]

            val = []
            for i in warehouse:
                w_code = i
                w_qty = warehouse[i]["qty"]

                val.append((str(dt), str(tm), str(SKU), str(w_code), str(w_qty)))
                df_tmp = pd.DataFrame([[dt, tm, SKU, w_code, w_qty]],
                                      columns=["SNP_DATE", "SNP_TIME", "SKU_CODE", "WAREHOUSE_CODE", "INVENTORY"])
                df_rabbit = pd.concat([df_rabbit, df_tmp])

            # Acknowledge the message
            channel.basic_ack(method_frame.delivery_tag)

            # Write to DB after every 1000 events
            if method_frame.delivery_tag % 1000 == 0:

                start = datetime.now()
                logging.info("Writing to DB...")
                df_rabbit.to_sql("inventory_snapshot_dev", conn, if_exists='append', index=False)


                end = datetime.now()
                logging.info("Time taken to write into DB: " + str(end-start))

                logging.info("Flushing dataframe......")
                #df_rabbit.drop(df_rabbit.index, inplace=False)
                df_rabbit = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["SNP_DATE", "SNP_TIME", "SKU_CODE", "WAREHOUSE_CODE", "INVENTORY"])

                logging.info("Flushing Done.")
    except:
        requeued_messages = channel.cancel()
        logging.info('Requeued %i messages' % requeued_messages)
    finally:
        channel.close()
        connection.close()
        conn.close()```
````